# Python: How do I sort on the second item of a tuple?

Tags: python

I have this piece of code

```
relations = dict()
relations[('a','b','c')] = 'first'
relations[('a','c','c')] = 'third'
relations[('d','b','c')] = 'second'

relations_sorted = sorted(relations.keys(), key=lambda tup: tup[1])

for key in relations_sorted:
  print( key, relations[key])
```

This prints the dictionary sorted on the second element of the key tuple (solution found on StackOverflow).

```
(('d', 'b', 'c'), 'second')
(('a', 'b', 'c'), 'first')
(('a', 'c', 'c'), 'third')
```

How do I extend this to sorting on the combination of second, then first, then third element in the tuple? E.g.

```
(('a', 'b', 'c'), 'first')
(('d', 'b', 'c'), 'second')
(('a', 'c', 'c'), 'third')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0], tup[2])`

or even faster/easier/better with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

relations_sorted = sorted(relations.keys(), key=itemgetter(1, 0, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to `key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0], tup[2])`